# Mixing GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG and normal Env vals in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in my docker-compose. How do I mix the GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG and capital letters env variables.

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:latest
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm

  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:10.3.3
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "30080:30080"
    - "30022:22"
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data:Z
    environment:
        GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
              external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:30080'
              gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022
    - DEBUG=true
    - DB_ADAPTER=postgresql
    - DB_HOST=postgresql
    - DB_PORT=5432
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production

    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379

    - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Berlin
```

I am getting error for the above config at the line `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG`.

> Error message here ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a
>   block mapping   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 5 expected
>   , but found '-'   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 39,
>   column 5

I am following an example here.[here](https://github.com/IBM/Kubernetes-container-service-GitLab-sample/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

My docker-compose version

```
 docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
docker-py version: 2.6.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is showing because the compose file presented is mixing between the two forms for specifiying [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)s for docker-compose:

The following should work:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:latest
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm

  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:10.3.3
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "30080:30080"
    - "30022:22"
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data:Z
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
              external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:30080'
              gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022
      DEBUG: 'true'
      DB_ADAPTER: postgresql
      DB_HOST: postgresql
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: gitlab
      DB_PASS: password
      DB_NAME: gitlabhq_production

      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379

      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      GITLAB_TIMEZONE: Berlin
```